# Complex and Conformal structure on a trivial tangent bundle of a higher dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, almost-complex

Let $M$ be an even dimensional Reimannian  manifold with **trivial** tangent bundle $TM$. Then there is a global orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2,...,e_{2n-1},e_{2n}\}$ of $TM$.

Define a bundle map $J :TM  \to TM$ which sends each $e_{2k-1}$ to $e_{2k}$ and 
 $e_{2k}$ to $-e_{2k-1}$ for $k=1,...,n$. Then, does this define a complex structure on $M$? Is it well-defined?

Ref

[Complex structure v.s. conformal structure in more than 1 complex dimension](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/132136/complex-structure-v-s-conformal-structure-in-more-than-1-complex-dimension)

[Proof of equivalence of conformal and complex structures on a Riemann surface.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661331/proof-of-equivalence-of-conformal-and-complex-structures-on-a-riemann-surface)

---

Edit for understanding the answer.

First, we show that $M = (S^2\times S^2)\#(S^1\times S^3)\#(S^1\times S^3)$  has a trivial tangent bundle and to do so, it suffices to show that

(I)  the Euler numbr of  $M$  is zero and

(II)  $M$ is a spin manifold.

Consider the (I).

For any triangularizable toplogical space $X$ and $Y$, there are simple algebraic relations between their Euler numbers.

$\chi(X \#Y) = \chi(X ) +\chi( Y)  -2,$

$\chi(X \times Y) = \chi(X ) \times \chi( Y). $

Using these formulas, we can calculate the Euler number of the manifold  $M = (S^2\times S^2)\#(S^1\times S^3)\#(S^1\times S^3)$ as follows.

$\chi(M) = \chi (S^2)\chi( S^2)+\chi(S^1)\chi( S^3)+\chi(S^1)\chi( S^3) -4.$

Because $\chi (S^2)=2$ and $\chi (S^1)=0$ and $\chi (S^3)=1-0+0-1=0$, we obtain

$\chi(M) = 2 \times 2 +0 \times \chi( S^3)+0 \times \chi( S^3) -4=0.$

Thus, $\chi(M)=0$ and thus (I) is O.K.

Next, consider the (II).

According to Albanese's comment, the connected sum of spin manifolds is spin.

Thus we show that the spaces $S^2\times S^2$, $S^1\times S^3$ and $S^1\times S^3$ are spin. To poove this, for example, we show $w_2(S^1\times S^3)=0$.

According to problem 4-A of page 54 in Milnor-Stasheff,

$w_2(S^1\times S^3)=w_2(S^1) \times  w_0(S^3) + w_1(S^1) \times  w_1(S^3)   + w_0(S^1) \times  w_2(S^3) =0$

where we use the total Stiefel-Whitney class of sphere is 1, namely, $w(s^d)=1$ (page 42 example 1 in Milnor Stasheff).

Comment: The connected sum of spin manifolds is spin, so the fact that $M$ is spin follows from the fact that $S^2\times S^2$ and $S^1\times S^3$ are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the fact that $M$ is Riemannian plays no role here.

The endomorphism $J$ is indeed well-defined and as $J\circ J = -\operatorname{id}_{TM}$, it is an almost complex structure on $M$. However, it need not be an *integrable* almost complex structure. That is, it may not be an almost complex structure induced by a complex manifold. For example, $M = (S^2\times S^2)\#(S^1\times S^3)\#(S^1\times S^3)$ has trivial tangent bundle and hence has an almost complex structure as you describe, but it does not admit a complex structure.

In real dimension two, every almost complex structure is integrable, see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/837343/39599). In real dimension four and above, there are examples of almost complex structures which are not integrable. In real dimension four, there are manifolds (such as $M$) which admit almost complex structures, none of which are integrable. It is an open problem whether such manifolds exist in real dimension six and above.

Comment: The example seems interesting but it is difficult for me. Please let me give a hint,key words, materials to verify why the manifold has trivial tangent bundle and it does not admit any integral complex structure.  I have no experience to  consider the tangent bundle of the connected sum. Also I understand the Reimannian metric is redundant   ( though, the almost complex structure is compatible with the metric?).

Comment: The fact that $M$ is parallelisable is a direct consequence of the Dold-Whitney Theorem which states two orientable real rank four bundles over a compact four-manifold are isomorphic if and only if they have the same second Stiefel-Whitney class $w_2$, first Pontryagin class $p_1$, and Euler class $e$. In particular, a compact four-manifold is parallelisable if and only if it is spin manifold with signature and Euler characteristic zero. The fact that $M$ does not admit a complex structure combines the following two facts: 1. If a compact complex manifold has fundamental group a free group ...

Comment: ... on a positive number of generators, then it does not admit a Kähler metric; 2. A compact complex surface admits a Kähler metric if and only if its first Betti number is even. So, if $M$ in my answer were to admit a complex structure, it would not admit a Kähler metric by the first point, but that is impossible by the second point. Therefore $M$ cannot admit a complex structure.

Comment: I need a time to understand. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I would estimate yes in the sense each 2n is mapped one-to-one in the sense each +2n may be mapped onto the pure reals for the real part of the complex mapping and each of the -2n may be mapped onto the pure imaginary numbers of the imaginary part of the complex system.  I am sorry here if will not do.  I am an economist, not a mathematician.  Sincerely,  Richard Anthony Baum